# Playing AVI files in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I can't seem to play my avi files using OpenCV. I am on a Mac and the files work with Quicktime and VLC player. I have tried using mencoder to convert it to i420 but that still has not been successful. No error messages occur and it seems like the program closes automatically and I'm not sure how to debug it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
    IplImage* frame;
    while(1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
}
```

Comment: When you step through it in your debugger, where does it abort?

Comment: It doesn't say a thing. It just exits normally.

Comment: Are you sure the filename you're giving as a command line argument is correct?

Try adding a check to ensure the file actually exists. If not, produce an error.

Comment: I'll add a check to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your code lacks error checking,  maybe there was a problem with cvCreateFileCapture() and you'll never know until you check the return of the function.

Anyway, you should either remove, or add a debug for this statement here:

```
if( !frame ) break;
```

Becouse if there was a problem retrieving the first frame of the file, your application would simply give up and quit silently, giving you the "nothing happened" feeling.

Changed it to something like:

```
if (!frame) { printf("Uow, huge fail!\n"); break;}
```

But most importantly: why are you not using cvCaptureFromAVI() ?
Check this out: http://nashruddin.com/How_to_Play_AVI_Files_with_OpenCV

Comment: I did try that method as well but I'll definitely put the debug messages in to see. Thanks!

Comment: I got the same problem. The first frame is not retrieved correctly. However, I use the test.avi and tree.avi file which provided by the textbook to test. What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't know @Kalla. I would have to see your source code. A lot of things could be wrong. Ask a question and then leave a comment with my name so I can follow you.