# 'Hello world' video program not working

Tags: c, opencv

I've bought the OpenCV book, and the very first video program isn't working. Before going further, I wonder if there is something wrong in my system. It's a very simple program, with very little to debug.

```
#include "highgui.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
    IplImage* frame;
    while(1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
}
```

It compiles normally, but when run, the program simply opens a white window for some seconds and then closes. There are no errors, apparently, just what looks like to be a deprecation warning. What could be wrong?

```
k♥t ./demo /opt/Media/Vídeos/Docs/Connections/Connections/02\ -\ Death\ in\ the\ Morning.avi 
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
k♥t
```

---

**EDIT:** Sorry for all the fuss, it was just a typo. Fix'd now.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? What OS? What IDE/build environment?

Answer (score 1):

I see lot of spaces in the file name you are passing as a parameter and you have mixed forward and backward slash. Please verify if the path and filename is valid.

Answer (score 1):

While normally you can escape spaces with a backwards slash, sometimes OpenCV can be fussy. I'd recommend renaming the video to a name without spaces and perhaps even copying into the same directory as your program while you test it.

If you have further problems with the avi file, you could have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252199/playing-avi-files-in-opencv) as well as the linked tutorial: http://nashruddin.com/How_to_Play_AVI_Files_with_OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

Add safety checks! Always verify the success of the functions you are calling:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
if (!capture)
{
    // Print error message! Failed to load file
}
```

It could be that it is failing to load the file.