# init done opengl support available

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, ubuntu, opencv

I have build OpenCV 2.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit platform with OpenGl,Qt and OpenNI but whenever I am running example programs listed in the Learning OpenCV Book.

For Example:

```
    #include "highgui.h"

    int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
        cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        //CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( argv[1] );
        CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
        IplImage* frame;
        while(1) {
            frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            if( !frame ) break;
            cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
            char c = cvWaitKey(33);
            if( c == 27 ) break;
        }
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
        cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
    }
```

I get this message in the console:

```
init done 
opengl support available
```

I wonder where I am going wrong.I am not getting any errors in compilation.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Does it crash?

Comment: Nothing..It builds completely and give this message in the console..In a program in which I am using it to display just a simple image, i get a window with black image with the same message down in the console

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but just to get it out of the way: are you sure you arguments are ok? (For example in the above code, is the argument a valid video file?)

Comment: Its okay Bob, I replaced the argument with the image with the image in the current directory.The Behavior is different for Images and Videos..In images I get black window and this message in console but in video i get this message and nothing else.

Comment: The first thing I would do is add debug statements everywhere to see what's called and what's going on in general. For example, when you read the image, apart from showing it, print the values also. Do they seem ok, or are they all black? See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252199/playing-avi-files-in-opencv?rq=1). It could be a library issue or the way OpenCV was built, but better eliminate easier possibilities first.

Comment: Hi Bob, I simplified the code to just print the height of the image
and its not even printing that also  but its not showing any compilation errors too  #include "highgui.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("1.jpg");
  cout<<img->height;
}

Comment: I had built OpenCV from this link http://www.samontab.com/web/2012/06/installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts/  ..Do you know any good link from where i could build opencv for a linux platform?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16672/discussion-between-bob-and-learner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error. I have a similar configuration on my machine and I see these statements every time I run something. These statements have nothing to do with what you have programmed. I have run your exact code and it displayed the video without any problems. Perhaps add this error check after you open the capture to make sure it found the video:

```
if (!capture) {
    std::cout << "COULD NOT OPEN CAPTURE\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Radford,I had figured it out that this was not an Issue :)..Those were my initial days with OpenCV!

Comment: Can you please tell the issue, I am having same problem.

Comment: This is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and then I added waitKey(0) at the end and the image was displayed.